# `isomorphic-fetch` response.json() method always throw Unexpected end of input error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I tried to use `isomorphic-fetch` with my `reactjs` application with `redux-thunk` middlewares. But I keep getting those `Unexpected end of input error` when I do

```
let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: "username=foo&password=bar"
};

fetch('my_url', config)
        .then(response => {
                response.json().then(user => ({user, response})) // here is where the error always been thrown
            })
```

even when server returns something like `{"user": "happy tree friends"}`.
Is there anything wrong with the way I'm use this module or my server just returns the wrong JSON data.

Help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your API, return `empty` so you get error

`JSON.parse('')` will throw `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, I have to configure my `tornado` server in order to work with the front-end part.

I'm doing a `CORS` request to the server, but adding some headers to the server default headers. The request worked:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def set_default_headers(self):
      self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, content-type")
      self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')

  def options(self):
      # no body
      self.set_status(204)
      self.finish()
```

@nour-sammour thank you! I went back to check my server and it was where the problem came from.